# function not working in html

Tags: php, html

i have viewed table from database and in each row added a button with onclick function but when i click on the button happens HTML code is below:

```
echo "<td> <button onclick = 'status(". $row['username'] .")'>Check Status</button></td>";
```

code for function is as below:

```
function status($getusername) {
$thisusername = $getusername;
printf($thisusername);
$results = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$thisusername'");
$level_user = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results);
$thisstatus = $level_user['status'];
switch ($thisstatus) {
case 0: 
      $query_date = "UPDATE users SET status= '1' WHERE username='$thisusername'";
  mysqli_query($db, $query_date);
      break;
case 1:  
    $query_date = "UPDATE users SET status= '0' WHERE username='$thisusername'";
 mysqli_query($db, $query_date);
     break;
}  
header('location: users.php');
}
```

i want to run the status function when "check status" is clicked.

Comment: do you know that you're trying to access a PHP method using a JS one? You need ajax for this.

Comment: any way i can do it with php cause i dont know ajex?

Answer (score -1):

Change this:

```
onclick = 'status(". $row['username'] .")'
```

to

```
onclick = "status(". $row['username'] .");"
```

Comment: getting this error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'status' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ';' i am using php echo to show html code